# How to access an Enum object inside a scala class

Tags: scala, enums

I'd like to know what the proper syntax is for accessing an enum inside a class, from both inside and outside it.

My code:

```
final class Celig {

  object eNums extends Enumeration {
    type eNums = Value
    val NAM, YEE = Value
  }

  // Here I'd like to assign a method that always returns a specific enum value
  var nammy = eNums.NAM
  def getNam: eNums.eNums = nammy
}
```

This code compiles, but it's on the ugly side.

I would like to know if a value of the Enum can be accessed in a cleaner way from inside the class, for example without the "eNums.eNums", and I'm also curious as to how to access a value of the enum from outside the class.

Edit: I would also like to know if it is possible to use a value in the default constructor that takes a value of the eNums type, for example, adding (car: Celig.eNums ) to the class header.

Thanks

Comment: You could `import eNums._` or `import Celig.eNums._`.  Then you'd have direct access to `NAM` and `YEE`, and type `eNums`, without the `eNums` prefix.

Answer (score 1):

Does something like the following do what you're looking for?

```
final class Celig {
  object ENums extends Enumeration {
    val NAM, YEE = Value
  }

  def getNam: ENums.Value = ENums.NAM
}
```

I would caution that `Enumeration` is generally not used very much in the world of Scala. Often we use `sealed trait`s or `sealed abstract class`es instead to simulate [algebraic datatypes](http://noelwelsh.com/programming/2015/06/02/everything-about-sealed/) which subsume `Enumeration`s.

In particular I would've probably rewritten your code something like the following:

```
sealed trait ENums
case object NAM extends ENums
case object YEE extends ENums

final class Celig {
  def getNam: ENums = NAM
}
```

This way of doing things has nice compiler support in the form of exhaustiveness checking for match statements and also allows for richer hierarchies than what `Enumeration` offers.

```
sealed trait ENums
case object NAM extends ENums
case object YEE extends ENums

final class Celig {
  def switchOnEnums(x: ENums): Int = x match {
    case NAM => 1
  }
}
```

results in

```
[info] Set current project to Test 1 (in build file:/scalastuff/)
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /scalastuff/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[warn] /scalastuff/src/main/scala/Main.scala:35: match may not be exhaustive.
[warn] It would fail on the following input: YEE
[warn]   def switchOnEnums(x: ENums): Int = x match {
[warn]                                      ^
[warn] one warning found
[success] Total time: 5 s, completed Sep 16, 2016 1:13:35 AM
```

And for a more complex hierarchy that still enjoys the compiler assisted exhaustiveness checking from before

```
sealed trait Day
case object Monday extends Day
case object Tuesday extends Day
// Got tired of writing days...

sealed trait Month
case object January extends Month
case object February extends Month
// Got tired of writing months...

sealed trait Date
case class CalendarFormat(day: Day, month: Month, year: Int) extends Date
case class UnixTime(sinceUTC: BigInt) extends Date
```

Comment: I've looked into Sealed traits, and chosen enums. I appreciate your time to make the suggestion, but it is not the option I'm going with here.

Comment: Also, unfortunately, I do need the Enum to be inside the Celig class, because the Enum values are a property of Celig. It's important that it be accessed in a way that makes it clear that the Enum is a property of all Celigs.

Comment: @sudom82 moved in the enumeration into Celig.

Comment: @sudom82 Fair enough about your `Enumeration` choice. I won't harp on it it, but I'll just leave this post here about some of the [thorns there](http://underscore.io/blog/posts/2014/09/03/enumerations.html) and also note that you can [iterate over sealed traits and case objects](https://github.com/mrvisser/sealerate) if that's what you're looking for.